# Integrade Jquery 1.5 with drupal 6 version... how?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, themes

How do i combine jquery 1.5 into drupal,
without breaking drupal functionality on drupal 6?
i tried jquery update, but its breaks some of the ajax built-in drupal functions...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Update shouldn't be breaking Drupal's built in ajax, and it should only upgrade Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2.  If so, you might report it to the maintainer.

You can always bring in a separate copy of jQuery and run it in no-conflict mode for whatever purpose you need it.  You could just map it to $j or whatever you wish.

See this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

specifically:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```